# Create customers without creating a charge using the Square Reader SDK

Tags: square-connect, square-reader

I am using the Square reader SDK for react native. I've figured out how to make a charge, but what I would like to be able to do is swipe someones card and then create a customer with a stored card in square without actually creating a charge at the time of the swipe. This is for registering someone at an event so I don't want to create the charge at the door, I just want to store their card for later. I see how I can create a customer and payment source using the commerce API but not using the reader API. Does anyone know if this is currently possible and if so, how I would approach it using the reader?

Answer (score 0):

There's currently not a way to do this through Reader SDK. There's no way to swipe a card without intentionally charging the card.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Are there any plans to add that functionality?